# Why are my values created in a for loop not working inside the body of the loop?

Tags: c++, if-statement, eigen

just had a quick couple questions as to why my I keep getting an error saying that x and y are not assigned a value at computeBarycentri2d(x, y, t.v) when in the if(!insideTriangle(x, y, t.v)) the values are assigned as an int value. The error I keep receiving for each value is "identifier x is not defined"

The other issue I am running into is that the continue statement in the if(zp >= depth_buf[y * width + x]) wont work giving me the error "a continue statement can only be used in a loop".

Any sort of help on how to fix these errors is greatly appreciated

```
void rst::rasterizer::rasterize_triangle(const Triangle& t, const std::array<Eigen::Vector3f, 3>& view_pos) 
    {
        std::array v = t.toVector4();
        float trix[3] = {t.v[0][0], t.v[1][0], t.v[2][0] };
        float triy[3] = {t.v[0][1], t.v[1][1], t.v[2][1] };
    
        std::pair<float*, float*> xrange = std::minmax_element(trix, trix + 3);
        std::pair<float*, float*> yrange = std::minmax_element(triy, triy + 3);
        for (int x = std::floor(*xrange.first); x < std::ceil(*xrange.second); ++x)
            for(int y = std::floor(*yrange.first); y < std::ceil(*yrange.second); ++y)
                if(!insideTriangle(x, y, t.v)) continue;
    
                auto[alpha, beta, gamma] = computeBarycentric2D(x, y, t.v);
                float Z = 1.0 / (alpha / v[0].w() + beta / v[1].w() + gamma / v[2].w());
                float zp = alpha * v[0].z() / v[0].w() + beta * v[1].z() / v[1].w() + gamma * v[2].z() / v[2].w();
                zp *= Z;
    
                if(zp >= depth_buf[y * width + x]) continue;
                depth_buf[y * width + x] = zp;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't use whitespace indenting to ascertain the scopes of `for` loops: you have to put `{` and `}` around multiline statement blocks that you want executed by the loop.  As is, your nested `for` loops do nothing, and the code from `auto[alpha`... onwards executed after the `for` loops have exited.

Comment: and compilers can warn about that

Comment: Funny you say that @Tony Delroy I had them originally without the brackets and added them to see if it helped. Ill revert back to how I had it and update the code

Comment: Why does the code from auto[alpha ... onwards exited?

Comment: You need curly braces in the `y` loop.  `for (int y = ...) {`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That did it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So from the help of @1201ProgramAlarm I found out that all i needed to do was add in brackets to each for loop which got rid of all of my errors!

Here is the code updated:

```
void rst::rasterizer::rasterize_triangle(const Triangle& t, const std::array<Eigen::Vector3f, 3>& view_pos) 
{
    
    std::array v = t.toVector4();
    float trix[3] = {t.v[0][0], t.v[1][0], t.v[2][0] };
    float triy[3] = {t.v[0][1], t.v[1][1], t.v[2][1] };

    std::pair<float*, float*> xrange = std::minmax_element(trix, trix + 3);
    std::pair<float*, float*> yrange = std::minmax_element(triy, triy + 3);
    for (int x = std::floor(*xrange.first); x < std::ceil(*xrange.second); ++x)
    {
        for(int y = std::floor(*yrange.first); y < std::ceil(*yrange.second); ++y)
        {
            if(!insideTriangle(x, y, t.v)) continue;

            auto[alpha, beta, gamma] = computeBarycentric2D(x, y, t.v);
            float Z = 1.0 / (alpha / v[0].w() + beta / v[1].w() + gamma / v[2].w());
            float zp = alpha * v[0].z() / v[0].w() + beta * v[1].z() / v[1].w() + gamma * v[2].z() / v[2].w();
            zp *= Z;

            if(zp >= depth_buf[y * width + x]) continue;
            depth_buf[y * width + x] = zp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that comments can disappear easily. To make this a full-blown answer you could add a bit more details like showing the fixed code